# how to solve (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED) , VM player for Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-17.04

I have a 64 bit pc and i downloaded `ubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64` and then
I tried to make a Ubuntu VM using Ubuntu 17.04 but is is giving me an error it says `failed to open disk image` here is the trace back.

```
Could not get the storage format of the medium 'C:\Users\User\Downloads\ubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).


Result Code: 
VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component: 
MediumWrap
Interface: 
IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda}
Callee: 
IVirtualBox {0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945}
Callee RC: 
VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

any help?

Comment: What is the exact size of that iso you downloaded? Most likely there was a problem with the download.

Comment: @n8te 968 MB (1,01,59,60,159 bytes)

Comment: Yeah, that's wrong. I have the exact same iso and mine is 1.5 GiB (1,609,039,872). Yours didn't download fully. Delete that one and redownload it.

Comment: @n8te okay thanks mate, i'll try and respond asap